# User Order By in .net with datatype date

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, date, sql-order-by

I try to use "Order by" to order a list of Dates beginning by the earliest in VB.Net.

The variables and methods are:

```
Dim SetupStart As DateTime 
Dim SetupTimeList As New List(Of Date)
```

'the methode p.ReadFieldDateTime is used to connect to an SQL database and read the field Setup Time

```
SetupStart = p.ReadFieldDateTime("Orders", "Setup Time", record)
SetupTimeList.Add(SetupStart)

Dim SetupTimeListeOrdered = from SetupTime In SetupTimeList
Order By SetupTime
```

I hope this code snippet makes sense, if it doesn't make any sense I would be glad if some one could show me how to order this list ascending by the earlist date.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense :)  But why haven't you simply tried it out yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `OrderBy(...)` extension for `IEnumerable` like this:

```
Dim SetupTimeListeOrdered = SetupTimeList.OrderBy(Function(d) d)
```

I'm not super sure about the `VB.NET` syntax though, sorry.

In C#: `List SetupTimeListOrdered = SetupTimelist.OrderBy(d => d);

Answer (score 0):

By testing the following code, it works good, I am not sure about the Method you are using to get the Date values:

Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim dtList As List(Of Date) = CreateListofDateTime()

```
    Dim NonOrderedList = From t In dtList

    Console.WriteLine("Non Ordered List")
    For Each item As DateTime In NonOrderedList
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString())
    Next

    Dim OrderedList = From t In dtList Order By t
    Console.WriteLine("Ordered List")
    For Each item As DateTime In OrderedList
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString())
    Next
End Sub

Function CreateListofDateTime() As List(Of DateTime)
    Dim dtValue As New DateTime()
    Dim ldtListTosendBack As New List(Of Date)()
    dtValue = DateTime.Now
    ldtListTosendBack.Add(dtValue)

    dtValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)
    ldtListTosendBack.Add(dtValue)
    dtValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)
    ldtListTosendBack.Add(dtValue)
    dtValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-9)
    ldtListTosendBack.Add(dtValue)
    dtValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)
    ldtListTosendBack.Add(dtValue)
    Return ldtListTosendBack
End Function
```